# What does the @ symbol mean in the error LNK2019?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, linker

I'm trying to resolve my linker error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WDC_ReadAddr32@16 referenced in function

I'm not sure what the @16 refers to.

I'm pretty sure I added the correct lib file to the project. I did a dump of the lib file using dumpbin.exe, and saw:

- _WDC_ReadAddr16@20
- _WDC_ReadAddr32@20
- _WDC_ReadAddr64@20
- _WDC_ReadAddr8@20

So I'm confused at why the linker would be looking for _WDC_ReadAddr32@16, even though it manage to link the other symbols inside that lib file.

The function prototype is:

DWORD DLLCALLCONV WDC_ReadAddr32(WDC_DEVICE_HANDLE hDev, DWORD dwAddrSpace,
    KPTR dwOffset, UINT32 *val);

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to compile. Also the lib file was compile in C so it had extern "C" around the methods, but I'm trying to use it in a C++ project.

Comment: It means you're linking against functions declared as `__stdcall`, which you will find if you hunt down the definition of `DLLCALLCONV`

Comment: It means that your prototype is incorrect. Check the parameters.

Comment: Yes DLLCALLCONV is defined as __stdcall. So I'm still confused as to why it would generated this linker error.

Comment: Link with [`/verbose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx), see what object depends on that symbol.  Use `dumpbin` on the library that you think exports that symbol to ensure the symbol is actually there.  Then make sure you're actually passing the right library to the linker.

Comment: Looks like the lib file has that function only defined for 20 bytes for the parameters while visual studio is looking for 16 bytes. It is a third party library that I'm using. Could it be a mismatch between 64bit vs 32bit, since I'm going to be using 32bit pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ sign refers to the [number of bytes of parameters for the function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/08/48616.aspx) per Raymond Chen

Answer (score 1):

This is [a function with __stdcall calling convention.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add KERNEL_64BIT to the C prepropressor defines. In this way, KPTR becomes 8 bytes instead of 4 and the linker will look for _WDC_ReadAddr32@20 in the library.

http://www.jungo.com/st/support/tech_docs/td43.html